# Retrieve connection Info of Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, connection, target, jsplumb

I'm trying to get the connection info of a jsPlumb element that has been dropped on the canvas, in the following manner. But, it mentions that the source and target IDs are undefined.

**JS Function**

```
function getConnectionDetails(element)
{
    var s,t;
    var elemId = element.id;
    elemId =  elemId.charAt(0);
    var inConId = elemId + "-in";
    alert("element: "+elemId+"\nConnection in source details: "+ inConId);
    var outConId =  elemId + "-out";

    jsPlumb.bind("jsPlumbConnection", function(element) {
        s=inConId.sourceId;
        t=inConId.targetId;
    });
    alert("Source ID of connection: "+ s+ "\nTarget ID of connection: "+t);

}
```

'elemId' gets the connector's Id and is supposed to retrieve the connections that are connected to it. In this case, one connector will have only one other connection.

'inConId' will hold the ID of the left anchor/connector and the 'outConId' will hold the ID of the right anchor/ connector and I need to determine to which other elements' connectors are these 2(inCon & outCon) are connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
function getConnectionDetails(element)
    {
        var clickedId =  element.id;
        clickedId = clickedId.charAt(0);
        var from = clickedId+"-out";
        var from1 = clickedId;
        clickedId = clickedId+"-in";
        var con=jsPlumb.getAllConnections();
        var list=[];
        for(var i=0;i<con.length;i++)
        {
            if(con[i].targetId==clickedId)
            {
                list[i] = new Array(2);
                list[i][0] = con[i].sourceId;
                fromStreamId =list[i][0];
                list[i][1] = con[i].targetId;
            }

            if(con[i].sourceId==from || con[i].sourceId==from1)
            {
                list[i] = new Array(2);
                list[i][0] = con[i].sourceId;
                list[i][1] = con[i].targetId;
                intoStreamId =list[i][1];
            }
        }
        fromStreamId = fromStreamId.charAt(0);
        getFromStreamName(fromStreamId);
        intoStreamId = intoStreamId.charAt(0);

    }
```